# Configure Theme / Style in Gradle on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-theme

In the manifest, I have `minSdkVersion="8"` and `targetSdkVersion="19"`. I have set these `minSdkVersion="8"` and `targetSdkVersion="19"` on Gradle build too.

Previously on Eclipse, all the color theme and pop up dialog will appear correctly to targetSdkVersion.

Now on Android Studio, the color theme and pop up dialog style look as to minSdkVersion.

Why is it so? How to fix this? I cannot set `minSdkVersion="19"` just for the sake of interface look and sacrifice users with lower version.

**Update: If I set `minSdkVersion="19"`I still need to explicitly state `android theme=@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault` to work as previously on Eclipse.**

Comment: Does it happen only in preview or in real device too?

Comment: @Apurva Yes it happened on real device